# How to take off the first result in a for loop so it does not repeat itself

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the number of greatest percent change of a csv file that the user wishes to see (ex: if the user wants to see the 3 greatest percent change in the file, the program should show so) but every time i execute my loop, the result seems to duplicate itself. I know i am missing something, but cannot figure that much as I am still in the process of learning c++

```
for (int x = 0; x < days; x++) {

            double original = s[0].percent_change;
            int maximum;
            //Loop that computes the stock whose percentage change increased the most

            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

                if (s[i].percent_change > original) {
                    original = s[i].percent_change;
                    maximum = i;
                }
            }
            cout << "\n\nThe greatest percent change is the date: " << endl;

            cout << s[maximum].date << endl;
            cout << s[maximum].adj_close << endl;
            cout << s[maximum].percent_change << endl;

        }
    }
```

//the "days" is actually the input from the user, and the number of results the user wants to see.

I expect the output to show different results, and not duplicate itself.

Comment: What is the outer `for (int x = 0; ...)` loop for?  You don't use `x` anywhere in the loop, so its body is going to have identical runs on each iteration.

Comment: It seems that nothing in your piece of code is changing states. So, it will shows the same results `days` times.

Comment: @Amadeus which part of my code should i change to change the state to the next result?

Comment: @jamesdlin i just thought of x=0 as a starter for the loop, should i change the x to something else to jump to the next result or do i create an if statement?

Comment: @kentcyrel it is your program, you should know that. But, looking at this piece of program, only `original` and `maximum` change values, and neither of them are used for anything, except (`maximum`) to show values.

Comment: There are many way to do it, but I'd advise you to make only one pass through `s`, keeping as many of the top results as you want. If you are familiar with the standard containers, `std::set` is useful.

Comment: You should **always** initialize variables. `maximum` is not getting initialized. If you were initializing it, you would likely noted that it's getting resetted on every pass of your "days" loop. You should put `int maximum= 0;` or `auto maximum= int(0);` above the `for` loop. Otherwise, it gets destroyed everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn’t make much sense. There is nothing within the main for-loop that depends on the loop’s `x` variable, so why should anything change? What would it behave differently the second time around?

The easiest solution might be to just sort the array, then pick off the top (or bottom) `days` elements.

See: [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> s = {5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3}; 

    // sort using the default operator<
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';

    // sort using a standard library compare function object
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());
    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';

    // sort using a custom function object
    struct {
        bool operator()(int a, int b) const
        {   
            return a < b;
        }   
    } customLess;
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), customLess);
    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';

    // sort using a lambda expression 
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int a, int b) {
        return a > b;   
    });
    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    } 
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```